# Is there a way to stop RealtimeDatabase's ValueEventListener from reading new data changes?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

So ValueEventListener will keep changing the app's data whenever there is a change in RealtimeDatabase.

I want to create a button that stops the ValueEventListener from keeping updating the app with new data. How to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So ValueEventListener will keep changing the app's data whenever there is a change in RealtimeDatabase.

Yes, that's correct. This is what a real-time listener does.

> I want to create a button that stops the ValueEventListener from keeping updating the app with new data. How to do that?

In the same you have added the listener, you can remove it. So in code, it should look like this:

```
stopListenerButton.setOnClickListener {
    databaseReference.removeEventListener(valueEventListener);
}
```

There is another approach in which you don't actually need to remove the listener. If need that, you can use [Query#addListenerForSingleValueEvent(@NonNull ValueEventListener listener)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query#addListenerForSingleValueEvent(com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener)):

> Add a listener for a single change in the data at this location. This listener will be triggered once with the value of the data at the location.

**Edit:**

This is how you create a listener using an anonymous object:

```
val listener = object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented") //Never ignore potential errors!
    }
}
```

This is how you attach the listener:

```
yourRef.addValueEventListener(listener)
```

And this is how you remove the listener:

```
yourRef.removeEventListener(listener)
```

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the answer, what is the value for `valueEventListener`? is it `databaseReference.ValueEventListener(object: ValueEventLister {   })` ?

Comment: No, only the anonymous object `object: ValueEventLister { ... }`. Give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: Hey Tommy. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Comment: Hi Alex, I am still trying to assign all of the `object: ValueEventListener { ... }` to a variable, for example: ``ref.ValueEventListener( var deleteThisLater = object: ValueEventListener { ... })`` so I can use it in `ref.removeEventListener(deleteThisLater)` but it seems it cannot be assigned like that. How to assign the `object: ValueEventListener { ... }` to a variable? Thanks

Comment: Please check my updated answer. Give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: Hi Alex, it works when they are in the same fragment, but when I send the listener to bottomsheetdialog, the removeEventListener does not take effect. Wonder why?

Comment: Without seeing the code, I cannot be much of a help. So please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.